# Reference loaded <img> in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-preloader

I use a carousel jQuery plugin which defines a container which must contain `<img>` tags. The images are loaded and shown, the carousel works.

I am now implementing image preview on hover. I've created a separate `<div>` for this purpose which is being shown with the loaded image.

The *problem* is that I'm programatically creating a new `<img>` tag within the `<div>` each time the mouse hovers over a different image. This results in massive amount of unnecessary server requests.

**How can I use preloaded images from the carousel within the image preview div?**

I don't need a fully working solution, I'll accept abstract answers.

Comment: If the images have already been loaded into the carousel, they're already preloaded. Also, preloading them isn't going to reduce the amount of server requests...

Comment: It is going to reduce the amount of server requests if the users hovers over the div several times. Also, OP, answering is hard without some dummy code.

Comment: @Propolys - only if the user has browser caching disabled, which, is exceedingly rare - far more rare than having JS disabled in the browser.

Comment: @Howie - what about just cloning the element that's hovered? Since the data has been loaded and decoded already, it should be light-weight and lightening fast.

Comment: @Howie - just tested the method. Yup, it's likely the way to go. I've tried it with a 7MB jpg (3264x4928px). The image takes a little over a second to load. I then make 3 clones of it and append them to the DOM. The 3 clones are added instantaneously. Also, there's no extra network traffic - even when I've got the browser cache disabled. Just use the `.cloneNode` method of the image element, and you're good to go. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: @enhzflep I haven't thought about that! You should formulate a proper answer out of your comment so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments, here's a working sample of the cloneNode method I mentioned. I've not bothered with the mechanics of the containers or of triggering the behaviour via a mouse hover, just click the existing image and it will work.
You'll also have to change the image source to something you already have. I'm testing with the full-res version of this image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SoundingRocketSamplePayload-02.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);
function onDocLoaded()
{
    byId('srcImg').addEventListener('click', myTest, false);
}

function myTest()
{
    var tgtElem = byId('srcImg');

    var clone1 = tgtElem.cloneNode(true);
    var clone2 = tgtElem.cloneNode(true);
    var clone3 = tgtElem.cloneNode(true);

    document.body.appendChild(clone1);
    document.body.appendChild(clone2);
    document.body.appendChild(clone3);
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id='srcImg' style='width: 256px' src='rockets.jpg'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funnily enough Chrome is the only browser that makes additional (albeit cached) server requests. I can see them in the access logs.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll have to take a closer look later this evening. Thanks!